# Chrome 51.0.2704.84 not requesting HTTP/2.0, but Safari an Firefox did

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, nginx, safari, http2

I has configed my nginx for a http2 service

```
    worker_processes 2;
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
    }

http {
    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate     /usr/cer/server.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/cer/server.key;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

and with log message

- Chrome 51.0.2704.84
- Safari 9.1.1
- Firefox 47.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/supporting-http2-google-chrome-users/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reason:

> To address this, Google developed a new transport layer named SPDY. SPDY was accessed over SSL/TLS, and Google developed an SSL/TLS modification called Next Protocol Negotiation (NPN) that allows clients to upgrade their SSL/TLS connections from HTTP/1 to HTTP/2. Major web servers (such as NGINX) implemented SPDY; OpenSSL and other SSL/TLS stacks implemented NPN.

solution

> Recompile NGINX from source and use a private build with OpenSSL 1.0.2